# Changing rel Attribute to data-rel in JQuery to Work with HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, rel

I am trying to implement a JQuery image gallery written for an XHTML 1.0 doctype to my HTML5 site, the problem is I cannot use custom "rel" attributes with HTML5:

```
<!-- In <head> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel='first_gallery']").colorbox({opacity: ".75"});
    $("a[rel='second_gallery']").colorbox({opacity: ".75"});
});
</script>

<!-- In <body> tag -->
<a href="first_gallery/1.jpg" title="Image 1" rel="first_gallery"><img src="images/1_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image 1 Thumbnail"/></a>

<a href="second_gallery/2.jpg" title="Image 2" rel="second_gallery"><img src="images/2_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image 2 Thumbnail"/></a>
```

I have tried using HTML5 custom "data-rel" atrributes instead of "rel" but what is wrong with my JQuery?

```
<!-- In <head> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[data-rel='first_gallery']").colorbox({opacity: ".75"});
    $("a[data-rel='second_gallery']").colorbox({opacity: ".75"});
});
</script>

<!-- In <body> tag -->
<a href="first_gallery/1.jpg" title="Image 1" data-rel="first_gallery"><img src="images/1_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image 1 Thumbnail"/></a>

<a href="second_gallery/2.jpg" title="Image 2" data-rel="second_gallery"><img src="images/2_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image 2 Thumbnail"/></a>
```

Comment: What would be wrong with using `id`?  And you really need to explain the exact problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced the same problem and I completely get what you are trying to achieve, but first I will fix the initial code where you use the "rel" attribute"

Please, notice that the "rel" attribute is an option within the jquery.colorbox object:

```
<!-- In <head> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").colorbox({ rel: "first_gallery", opacity: ".75"}); // this means <a rel="first_gallery" …>
    $("a").colorbox({ rel: "second_gallery", opacity: ".75"}); // this means <a rel="second_gallery" …>
});
</script>

<!-- In <body> tag -->
<a rel="first_gallery" href="first_gallery/1.jpg" title="Image 1"><img src="images/1_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image 1 Thumbnail"/></a>
<a rel="second_gallery" href="second_gallery/2.jpg" title="Image 2"><img src="images/2_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image 2 Thumbnail"/></a>
```

As you know, the example above will not validate as HTML5 since the values for "rel" will not validate.

If you want to use "data-rel" your code should look like this:

```
<!-- In <head> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").colorbox({ rel: $(this).data('rel'), opacity: ".75"});
});
</script>
```

`rel: $(this).data('rel')` tells jquery.colorbox to use "data-rel" to wrap up galleries. It's somewhate limited: you cannot use a custom "data-" attribute nor the value in "data-rel".

The code above will work for both of your galleries using "data-rel":

```
<!-- In <body> tag -->
<a data-rel="first_gallery" href="first_gallery/1.jpg" title="Image 1"><img src="images/1_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image 1 Thumbnail"/></a>
<a data-rel="second_gallery" href="second_gallery/2.jpg" title="Image 2"><img src="images/2_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image 2 Thumbnail"/></a>
```

The disadvantage comes if you would like to set different options for different galleries, let's say different opacity, a practical example will be:

```
<!-- In <head> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.gallery1").colorbox({ rel: $(this).data('rel'), opacity: ".75"});
    $("a.gallery2").colorbox({ rel: $(this).data('rel'), opacity: ".80"});
});
</script>

<!-- In <body> tag -->
<a class="gallery1" data-rel="first_gallery" href="first_gallery/1.jpg" title="Image 1"><img src="images/1_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image 1 Thumbnail"/></a>
<a class="gallery2" data-rel="second_gallery" href="second_gallery/2.jpg" title="Image 2"><img src="images/2_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image 2 Thumbnail"/></a>
```

I hope i did not confuse you with the explanation.

Comment: This worked very well, thank you for the Colorbox data-rel solution

Answer (score 0):

noting wrong with it.

it works just fine.

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/NCrmb/

if you are having problems (you didnt say what is happening or what is supposed do happen), it could be somewere else.

Comment: Hi, the problem is it doesn't validate with HTML5. The code was originally written for an XHTML 1.0 doctype which allows for custom rel attribute values, but HTML5 doesn't. Thus I'm trying to get around that using data-rel instead, but now the JQuery isn't working. I know there's a way to modify the code to make it work with data-rel, but I'm a JQuery n00b.